# Can the return type of onPostExecute method in AsyncTask be not void?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android app, which requires the use of **AsyncTask** for Network connection. I have executed the **doInBackground** method and passed the return value to **onPostExecute** method. I want to return some value from **onPostExecute** method back to the function from which it is called(I knw, onPostExecute executes in the main thread). Is this possible? Is it like, **onPostExecute** return type must be void?? If not, what do u suggest?

Thanks in advance
Maneesh

Answer (score 1):

If you want AsyncTask to return a value that would be captured directly, you need a blocking call, which defeats the purpose of AsyncTask.

What you should do is extend AsyncTask or wrap it, then create a field containing the value you wish to return, and set it from within onPostExecute. Then in your code, hold a reference to your AsyncTask and check that value once the task is finished.

Comment: Thanks JRL..But what do u mean by wrapping AsyncTask..How do u do it? Can u elaborate in detail?